# Htaccess - redirect if url contains a " symbol

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to set a rule in .htaccess to redirect the following URL:

```
example.com/custom-path/”jack”/
```

to

```
example.com/custom-path/jack/
```

In a nutshell, I just want to remove `”` and redirect (301) to the correct URL (same URL without `”` ).

What htaccess rule should I use to do that?

Comment: Have a look at [W3C URL encode page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) : there you see you should replace the `"` with `%22`.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use the following Rule in your `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /custom-path/%22jack%22 [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://exmaple.com/custom-path/jack [L,R=301]
```